# Does a Runnable continue after device comes out sleep mode in Android

Tags: android, sleep

If my activity launches a Runnable and then the device goes into sleep mode, will the Runnable be paused and then continue from where it left off after coming out of sleep mode?

Comment: Runnable is just an interface and cannot be paused or resumed, all depends on what object uses this interface

Comment: That doesn't explain what happens to the Runnable when sleep mode kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does.

**But**, you won't get an expiry while the phone is asleep. Time isn't counted while the phone is asleep so you get the following (possibly) unintuitive behavior:

t=  0s: Set timeout for 1 minute
t= 20s: Phone goes to sleep
t= 40s: Phone wakes up
t= 60s: You expect your alarm but you don't get it
t= 80s: Your alarm fires because the 20s sleep time wasn't counted!

If you don't like this you can user the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class. It's harder to use and costs more system resources but it counts time spent in sleep and will wake the device.